# How to numerically implement a Wick rotation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, complex-numbers, time-evolution, wick-rotation

I'm solving a Schroedinger-type differential equation using numerical methods (RK4 for precision, explicit Euler to get a rough idea). I have an initial condition to start. I understand that replacing $t \to it$ performs a Wick rotation, but I have trouble interpreting the solution that I get out from RK4/Euler schemes.

Essentially when I do the replacement I get out a diffusion-type equation, which then my numerical method can solve for and time-evolve. But since I do not have control over the time variable, I cannot back-substitute $t \to -it$ to evolve the solution to the Schroedinger-type equation.

I've heard it said that imaginary time evolution is only good for finding ground states (not applicable to time-evolving your initial condition), but I'm having trouble seeing that.

My intuition mainly relies on this connection between diffusion and Schroedinger equations, which isn't ideal. How is Wick rotation performed in the context of some common numerical methods?